# store the result of xpath into an variable to assist in future query

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl some of the website. I am new to both Scrapy and XPath. This question is on XPpath.

As mentioned in the question title I want to store the selected node in a variable. and I want to further query but not on the entire html. I just want to query on the loaded variable. So let me explain what happens

let the sample html page be:

```
<sample>
    <tag attribute="I NEED THIS">
        <common1>
            Area to be processed first 
        </common1>
        <common2>
            Area to be processed later
        </common2>  
    </tag>  

    <tag attribute="I DON'T NEED THIS">  
        <common1>
            Not interested in this part    
        </common1>
        <common2>
            Again not interested here
        </common2>
    </tag>
</sample>
```

Now I want to process "tag" with attribute "I NEED THIS"

so I do :

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

needed = hxs.select('//sample/tag[@attribute="I NEED THIS"]')
```

and later when I do the following :

```
common1 = needed.select('//common1')
```

I get both the `common1` tag elements present in the whole document not just from needed variable. I want some assistance here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use relative xpath:

```
.//common1
```

See [Working with relative XPaths](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths) in scrapy docs.

Comment: oh... yes. Sorry I missed that part